How to Track Event Labels and Categories with Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?
I've recently migrated from Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4 (GA4) and I'm having trouble replicating the event tracking and reporting I used to have. In Universal Analytics, I tracked video clicks with the following setup:
HTML:
<a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'timeline', '4', 'video_id:44432', 1, {nonInteraction: true } );">
    <img src="/img/image1.jpg">
</a>

Reporting Request:
body = {
    "reportRequests": [
        {
            "viewId": VIEW,
            "pageSize": 10000,
            "samplingLevel": "LARGE",
            "dateRanges": [
                {"startDate": "7daysAgo", "endDate": "today"}
            ],
            "metrics": [
                {"expression": "ga:totalEvents"},
                {"expression": "ga:eventValue"},
            ],
            "dimensions": [
                {"name": "ga:eventLabel"},
                {"name": "ga:eventAction"},
                {"name": "ga:eventCategory"},
            ],
        }
    ]
}

This setup allowed me to count clicks on images and associate them with specific videos using the event labels and categories.
Now with GA4, I have this HTML setup:
<a href="#" 
   onclick="gtag('event', 'timeline', { 'event_category': 'video_interaction', 'event_label': '4', 'value': 1, 'video_id': 'video_id:44432', 'non_interaction': true });">
   <img src="/img/image1.jpg">
</a>

And the reporting request:
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import RunReportRequest, DateRange, Dimension, Metric

request = RunReportRequest(
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",
    dimensions=[
        Dimension(name="eventName"),
    ],
    metrics=[Metric(name="eventCount"), Metric(name="eventValue")],
    date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="7daysAgo", end_date="today")],
)

response = client.run_report(request)

# Response example
for row in response.rows:
    print(row)

The response I get is:
rows {
    dimension_values {
      value: "timeline"
    }
    metric_values {
      value: "11941"
    }
    metric_values {
      value: "11941"
    }
}

This is completely unusable for my needs because eventLabel doesn't exist anymore. I need to be able to differentiate which images were clicked and associate them with their respective videos.
How can I achieve similar tracking and reporting in GA4? Is there a way to include additional dimensions such as event_category and event_label in the report? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
